# Error running cypher query with Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

When I run in Python 3.4 with PyNeo 2.0.7 & Neo4J 2.2.1 I got this error
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable but it seems right according PyNeo documentation here (http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html)

```
from py2neo import  authenticate,Graph
authenticate("localhost:7474", "XXXX", "XXXX")
graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data")
query = "MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 10"
result = graph.cypher.execute(query)
```

Comment: You are getting the error on which line?

Comment: line 5: it tells that I can't use a object str as a parameter of execute

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem simply rebooting neo4j server which doesn't make me understand what happened but now it works.